# I want to delete the first 8 characters in the name of 322 files

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have 322 files and all of them start with `"533682 - "` ( this is what i want to remove from them ) i use this script but didn't worked:

```
for file in 533682*
do 

    mv $file $(echo $file | sed -e 's/^........//')

done
```

Comment: Is it 8 characters or 9 characters that you need to remove? `"533682 - "` is 9 characters: 6 numbers, 2 spaces, 1 hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the filenames contain spaces, you need to quote the variable and command substitution so they're treated as a single argument.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in 533682*;
do
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/^........//')"
done
```

You can also use the shell's built-in substring operator instead of `sed`.

```
mv "$file" "${file:8}"
```

In general, get in the habit of *always* quoting your variables. Only leave them unquoted when you have a good reason.

Comment: <code> mv: cannot move '533682 -001 - Getting Started With This Course.mp4' to '': No such file or directory <code> 
and if i do with out quotes:
<code> mv: target 'Course.mp4' is not a directory <code>

Comment: @Newb Are you sure you're using `bash`, not some other shell like `dash`?

Comment: yes im very shure that i'm using bash
!/bin/bash
first line of my script.... i'm using ubuntu 18.04 btw

Comment: @Newb Are you running it with `./script` or `sh script`? Use the former, the latter is wrong.

Comment: @Newb It should be `#!` not just `!`.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you, but I changed my answer to use `sed`.

Comment: @Newb BTW, use backticks around code in comments, not `<code>`

Comment: `\`show code here\`` instead of `<code>show code here</code>`

Comment: Since the prefix is fixed and short, you can use the POSIX-compliant `${file#????????}` as well.

Comment: @Barmar: I think the string to be removed is actually 9 characters `533682 - ` according to the question.

Comment: yeah its was 9, i miscalculated the one space after the -, but i figure it out, thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

With Perl's standalone `rename` command:

```
rename 's/^.{8}//' 533682*
```

Comment: This works flawleslly too, thanks its simpler but you need to install rename

Comment: @Newb: Maybe you already have `prename` installed, so you don't need to install `rename`.

Comment: No i didnt had it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `find` and `mv`:

```
find . -name "533682*" -execdir bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0:9}"' {} \;
```

So recursively:

```
533682 - somefile
```

Becomes:

```
somefile
```

Comment: Isn't the offset of the substring off? Should be `"${0:8}"`, no?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I was accounting for `./` from the returned find result, although you made me realize something! — that won't work recursively... `execdir` should be used instead! :)

Comment: Uh, and I meant 9 ;) Nice solution using `-execdir`!